How to serialize a Map[String, Any] with jsoniter
I'd like to adopt jsoniter, a wonderful JSON serailizer lib for Scala.  I'm using Scala 3.
The only stopper is that I need to serialize this:
Map[String, Any]

Where Any is a class where a given codec is available, like e.g. String, Date, Int, ....
Maybe the solution could be writing a custom codec, and I need probably to use reflection.  But I don't know how to start. I've seen the generated codec for a Map[String, Int].
Or perhaps it could be easier with another JSON scala parser lib.
I know that json4s can handle it with Scala 2, but it is buggy in Scala 3.  It uses reflection.

One way would be to pass a type class as a type bound:
given [A: JsonValueCodec]: JsonValueCodec[Map[String, A]] =
  JsonCodecMaker.make
// the same as
given [A](using JsonaValueCodec[A]): JsonValueCodec[Map[String, A]] =
  JsonCodecMaker.make

The limitation is that Jsoniter Scala provides ONLY semiautomatic derivation and values of JsonaValueCodec are provided by the library ONLY with JsonCodecMaker.make (no given: String, Int, Maps, Lists, etc, OOTB), so if you need JsonValueCodec[Map[String, Int]] with the given above, you'd have to additionally do:
given JsonValueCodec[Int] = JsonCodecMaker.make

summon[JsonValueCodec[Map[String, Int]]]

Since it's a bit inconvenient you can also make use of inline to let the macro resolve things at compile time:
inline given [A]: JsonValueCodec[Map[String, A]] = JsonCodecMaker.make

summon[JsonValueCodec[Map[String, Int]]]

As a matter of the fact, one could introduce automatic derivation with Jsoniter for any supported type, not just Maps using:
// allows overriding config with:
//  inline given config: CodecMakerConfig = CodecMakerConfig.addSomeOption
//  summon[A]
inline given [A]( 
  using inline config: CodecMakerConfig = CodecMakerConfig
): JsonValueCodec[A] = JsonCodecMaker.make(config)

summon[JsonValueCodec[Map[String, Int]]]

However, I would be careful: Jsoniter was build with semiautomatic derivation in mind (so that you wouldn't create intermediate codecs, just to compose them, and impose an overhead), and using it like this is not officially supported. (And author is adamant that he will never add official support for automatic derivation). It might impose some performance penalty (or maybe even some bugs).
But it's quote convenient, so if you are testing your code and benchmarking it, you should notice any issue if it happens. There is a good chance you will NOT run into any issues, and when there will be some performance concerns, then you will remove import with that automatic derivation and add semiautomatic derivation instead.

Good answer, it has opened me a new exciting door.  But what about if A can be different types?  Example: `Map("one" -> 1, "two" -> "TWO")

Then I would suggest addiing jsoniter-circe to the project and encoding the type as Map[String, Json]. No compile time reflection library is able to work with Any, as it is an open hierarchy - even if someone wrote a macro which scans your class paths and creates value match { /* case for every single class  found*/ }, you could pack that project into JAR, add to another project, and it would add a new class and use in it Map - it's by design impossible to handle. At best you can constrain values into something sealed e.g Circe's Json (there is a codec for it) /1

... and then manually handle the dispatch of the sealed type (e.g. decode Circe's JSON in parsedMap.map { case (key, json) => ... }). You could alternatively use something like sum type, but no library on Scala 3 that I know is able to handle it OOTB, so you'd have to derive macros for each element and "merge" them manually (it would be simpler to create Encoder/Decoder for Circe's JSON e.g. with orElse and narrow to combine codecs for different types). /2

Actually, decoder for Any can be done and, for example, scala-yaml library does try its best to parse yaml nodes to closest jvm type for an Any field but that's... just wrong. While you could write a decoder for Any for jsoniter-scala, don't do it. Either propose a sensible shape to substitute for A or use Json from jsoniter-circe like @MateuszKubuszok mentioned.

I've tried handling of circe.Json with jsoniter and works very well.
